# C# Converting MMddyy formated string to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have string in format MMddyy for example '112192' which I need to convert in DateTime object.

If I tried to split string and use `new DateTime(yy, mm, dd);` but is sets year as 0092. But I needed it as 1992.

I am also tried this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MMddyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

But it returns date with DateTime.MinValue

Comment: your code gives me the expected result

Comment: @UthistranS. strange... I am trying exactly that, but its returning min value

Comment: yes @RandomThoughts also your code is working

Comment: try to get your year value as string by this `string year = date.ToString("yyyy")` and see what  happen

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do it by this way

```
string str = "112192";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy"));
```

Also, your approach is working

```
DateTime date;
string str = "112192";
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MMddyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy"));
```

Comment: greate, happy coding

Comment: However its still not working with my code... Strange issue. I have recently updated to 4.6 framework. Not sure if its due to same...

Comment: maybe or maybe somewhre else, no problem use one working solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue like this:

```
string strdate = "9/10/2017"; // mm/dd/yyyy 
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strdate, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); Console.WriteLine(oDate.Day);
Console.WriteLine(oDate.Day);
```