# Get date part from filenames and sort based on the latest date using c#

Tags: c#, file, date, sorting, directory

I have a set of files in the directory with the name db.dat.01-30-2021,db.dat.01-30-2020,db.dat.01-30-2018,db.dat.02-28-2021,db.dat.02-28-2019.The date is appended to these files.I want get the latest file first in the order like below.I tried using CreationTime and lastwriteaccesstime but its not giving the desired result. Pls help to get files in this order.

```
db.dat.02-28-2021
db.dat.01-30-2021
db.dat.01-30-2020
db.dat.02-28-2019
db.dat.01-30-2018

Code

 DirectoryInfo dpdirectorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\wfiles");
 FileInfo[] files = dpdirectorySelected.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
                    
 foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
 {
  var f=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName);
 }
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: You should be able to use `Path.GetExtension` to extract the date part of the filename (since that's effectively the extension), and then the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043455/3181933) to parse it (don't forget to add the `-` in the appropriate places to match your date format).

Comment: Is the date in the filename meant to be the same as the CreationTime?

Comment: db.dat.01-30-2018
db.dat.01-30-2020
db.dat.01-30-2021
db.dat.02-28-2019
db.dat.02-28-2021

Comment: @KingOfArrows It's not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sortedFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "db.dat.*")
    .OrderByDescending(file => DateTime.ParseExact(Path.GetExtension(file), ".MM-dd-yyyy", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

CreationTime is `Date created:`, while LastAccessTime is `Date accessed:` and LastWriteTime is `Date modified:`. These are unaffected by the date appended to the file

[image: File Properties Image] [image: File Properties Image]

You can use `FileInfo.Extension`(Inherited from [`FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension?view=net-5.0)) to get the date part since it's effectively the extension.

Since the dates are already padded, you can just swap out `p.CreationTime` for `p.Extension`. To ensure the sorting is the same, you can append [`StringComparer.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantculture?view=net-5.0) to the OrderBy call.

```cs
db.dat.02-28-2021
db.dat.01-30-2021
db.dat.01-30-2020
db.dat.02-28-2019
db.dat.01-30-2018

Code

 DirectoryInfo dpdirectorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\wfiles");
 FileInfo[] files = dpdirectorySelected.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.Extension, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToArray();
                    
 foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
 {
  var f=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName);
 }
```